# Confirm box when browser/Tag close button clicks

Tags: javascript

I have created my website for this I like to create confirm box when user clicks browser close button.....

So i created my coding as

```
window.onbeforeunload = bunload;
    function bunload() {
        dontleave = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
        return dontleave;
            }
```

By this coding I got confirm box for each and every time when browser get loading.....I need confirm box when user only clicks browser close button......

Can anyone give me a idea

Comment: Not possible AFAIK. onbeforeunload is as good as it gets

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an if condition like below to your code.

```
if(event.clientY < 0){
window.onbeforeunload = bunload;
function bunload() {
    dontleave = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
    return dontleave;
        }
   }
```

This worked for me on IE8.

Comment: upon which browser did you try this?